# Running a postscript file on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, ghostscript, postscript

i have written a small c++ code to generate a postscript file. i have installed ghostscript viewer. i am trying to open .ps file in cygwin but got this below error.

```
$ gs.exe fill_rect_chd.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GPL Ghostscript 9.15: Cannot open X display `(null)'.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
GPL Ghostscript 9.15: Cannot open X display `(null)'.
Unrecoverable error: ioerror in setpagedevice
Operand stack:
    true  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--
```

I am new to postscript. this is the code present in the .ps file

```
$ cat fill_rect_chd.ps
1 0 0 setrgbcolor
0 0 moveto
100 0 lineto
100 100 lineto
0 100 lineto
 fill
```

Can anyone please suggest/Help me out with  this error.

Comment: What's the relevance of [tag:C++] here? Removed the tag. Show C++ code when asking about it.

Comment: It looks like you're not running an X server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you need to (install and) run the x.org X-server program (that comes with Cygwin: select the X11:`xinit` package) in order to open the graphical window. Or you can install the Windows version of ghostscript.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out on Cygwin but i installed GSview on my windows and this opens a ".ps" file easily.

Thank you all for the help and i will install server X and check.